# How to access a GLB's Skeleton when using Aframe's entity gltf-model to load it?

Tags: aframe, gltf

I'm following this spec for loading GLB's, https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/components/gltf-model.html,

i've loaded a GLB file using

this format.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity gltf-model="./assets/models/Streetbud_1.7.glb"
  move position=".5 1.5 -15" scale="5 5 5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

If i then access the model, i see the following in the console.

[Model without skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTyQu.png)

If i load the same model using the gltfloader from three.js with..

```
     gltfLoader.load('./assets/models/Streetbud_1.7.glb', (gltf) => {
....
    }
```

i get the following.

[Model with Skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paVrl.png)

Notice, in the case of the gltfLoader, the Skeleton is available in the model.    I don't have this option when using the Aframe entity.

I'm looking to retarget some BVH animations to my skeleton.  Any ideas on how i can get the skelton populated using ?  I prefer to use the newer approach for compatibility reasons with some other libraries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work like this:

1. wait until the model is loaded
2. find the root mesh object with `getObject3D('mesh')`
3. traverse it looking for the [`isSkinnedMesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/SkinnedMesh.isSkinnedMesh) flag.
4. access the `skeleteon` property.

---

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("skinnedMesh-logger", {
   init: function() {
     this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
       const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
       mesh.traverse(node => {
         if (!node.isSkinnedMesh) return;
         console.log(node); // or node.skeleton
       })
     })
   }
})
```